# Validate user input C#

Tags: c#, sql, validation, user-input

How can I check if the user has entered a number in a Text field? If they do enter data other than text I want an error message to display and loop back to take their input again.. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here's the code:

```
myCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Guest(Guest_First_Name, Guest_Surname, Guest_Address, Guest_Postcode, Guest_Telephone, [Guest_E-mail])" + "VALUES(@Fname, @Sname, @Address, @Postcode, @Telephone, @Email)";

        myCmd.Parameters.Add("@Fname", OleDbType.Char).Value = firstName.Text;
        myCmd.Parameters.Add("@Sname", OleDbType.Char).Value = surname.Text;
        myCmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", OleDbType.Char).Value = address.Text;
        myCmd.Parameters.Add("@Postcode", OleDbType.Char).Value = postcode.Text;
        myCmd.Parameters.Add("@Telephone", OleDbType.Char).Value = telephone.Text;
        myCmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", OleDbType.Char).Value = email.Text;

        connect.Open();
        int rowsChanged = myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connect.Close();

        if (rowsChanged == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Record Not Inserted");
        }
```

Comment: @Lioyd..Use Server side validation controls or write keypress event

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @LIoyd Numbers are not the only characters that I think you don't recognize as text. In fact I think that you need something like regular expression to check for `[a-z][A-Z]` or something.

Comment: Or you can use the `Char.IsLetter(ch)` as described here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and check each char.

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume that textField is the name of field. Then you can do the following in C#:-

```
int num=0;
if(!(Int32.TryParse(textField,out num)))
{
Console.WriteLine("Error");
return;  // return an error at this point
}
```

You can also try the following (untested) :-

```
int num=0;
if(!(Int32.TryParse(textField,NumberStyles.None,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,out num)))
{
Console.WriteLine("Error");
return;  // return an error at this point
}
```

In the first example, the NumberStyles defaults to Integer. Changing it to None might help.

Comment: I wouldn't say that everything that can not be parsed to `Int` is text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that method is partially working.. if I numbers and then a letter it would accept it and insert it into the database :/ how would I stop it from doing this?

Comment: what is the input that you are giving ?

Comment: Also, added another code. Check if that solves the issue

Comment: Hi Max, tried your method but the NumberStyles and CultureInfo get a red underline saying they do not exist in the current context. How would I solve this error? Thanks, Lloyd

Comment: please add the following statement on top of .cs file :-

using System.Globalization

             the above two classes exist in System.Globalization namespace

Answer (score 1):

Could use something like this:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = string.Concat(textBox1.Text.Where(char.IsLetter));
}
```

This wouldn't show any errors; anything other than letters would just be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
int result;
if (int.TryParse(input.Text, out result))
{
    // it's a valid integer => you could use the result variable here
}
```

or if you want to validate in keypress,

```
private void txtbox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar >= '0' && e.KeyChar <= '9' || e.KeyChar == '')  
    {
        e.Handled = false; //Do not reject the input
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = true; //Reject the input
    }
}
```